# Not able to edit the email Id

Tags: configuration

As an admin,i tried to update the email id of the user.The user got an email 'Finish changing your Salesforce account’s email address'.However,when the user clicked on the link got insufficient Privileges(user is also a system administrator).

Comment: Usually, what I have seen is when you update user email or reset a password in a sandbox org, salesforce sends an email with a link for the user to click and the url might be pointing to login.salesforce.com. This causes the link not to work.

Can you check and let me know if this is the case? If not, can provide some screenshots of the error and the org type (sandbox/production)?

Comment: Url is pointing to the sandbox and i am trying to update the email id in the sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps to try:

1. Make sure that the link (when clicked from email client/browser) opens with the exact url opens without any truncation.
2. Check if user is frozen or inactive (through IP restrictions).
3. Check if any permission sets have been assigned/updated.

[Reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/salesforce/comments/8qseoo/insufficient_privileges_when_clicking_on/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/91270)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @DaveHumm. Much appreciated. I have updated the answer with the points and also included the reference link.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek Sivasubramanian. I always want to help people improve their answers for the community.